# Summing data into pivot style in same table with different predicate

Tags: sql-server, sum, pivot

I have this data:

```
procedure     proc_time     proc_old_new
=========     =========     ============
Proc1                 3     Old
Proc2                 5     Old
Proc1                 2     New
Proc3                 4     Old
Proc3                 6     New
Proc2                 3     Old
Proc3                 8     New
```

And want to display it like this:

```
procedure     Old           new            total   Avg
=========     =========     ============   =====   ===
Proc1                 3                2       5   2.5
Proc2                 8                        8   8
Proc3                 4               14      18   9
```

I have tried various different methods such as a pivot but couldn't work out how to create this as a pivot. I have done a simpler pivot before but this one is a bit of a struggle, especially trying to work out how to sum the different parts and combine them for the old and new procedures, and put old and new in different columns.

appreciate any help or pointers on this

Thanks

Andrew

Update: New Data Display for further ideas about calculating average:

```
   Procedure        Intermediate      New       Old      Total   avg
   Proc1                       6        0         0        6     2.000000
   Proc2                      74       13         0       87     29.000000
   Proc3                      29        0         0       29     9.666666
   Proc4                      16        0         0       16     5.333333
```

So in line 1 I would want the average to be 6 instead of divided by 3, effectively divided by 1. Line 2 total divided by 3 etc. Would I be able to do a dynamic denominator for an average calculation?

Answer (score 1):

I would use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to convert the `old` and `new` values into columns, then you can easily get the `total` and `average` using `sum()` and `avg()`:

```
select
    [procedure],
    SUM(case when proc_old_new = 'Old' then proc_time else 0 end) Old,
    SUM(case when proc_old_new = 'New' then proc_time else 0 end) New,
    SUM(proc_time*1.0) Total,
    sum(proc_time*1.0)/2 [avg]
from mytable
group by [procedure];
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57e0e0/1). This gives a result:

```
+-----------+-----+-----+-------+----------+
| procedure | Old | New | Total |   avg    |
+-----------+-----+-----+-------+----------+
| Proc1     |   3 |   2 | 5.0   | 2.500000 |
| Proc2     |   8 |   0 | 8.0   | 4.000000 |
| Proc3     |   4 |  14 | 18.0  | 9.000000 |
+-----------+-----+-----+-------+----------+
```

You desired result is not exactly clear but if you want to only average based on whether the `old`/`new` value is not null, then you could also use:

```
;with cte as
(
    select
        [procedure],
        sum(case when proc_old_new = 'Old' then proc_time end) Old,
        sum(case when proc_old_new = 'New' then proc_time end) New
    from mytable
    group by [procedure]
)
select [procedure],
    Old,
    New,
    coalesce(Old, 0) + coalesce(New, 0) Total,
    AVG(value) [avg]
from cte
cross apply
(
    select cast(old as decimal(10, 2)) union all 
    select cast(new as decimal(10, 2))
) c(value)
group by [procedure], Old, New
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57e0e0/2). This version gives a result:

```
+-----------+-----+------+-------+----------+
| procedure | Old | New  | Total |   avg    |
+-----------+-----+------+-------+----------+
| Proc1     |   3 | 2    |     5 | 2.500000 |
| Proc2     |   8 | NULL |     8 | 8.000000 |
| Proc3     |   4 | 14   |    18 | 9.000000 |
+-----------+-----+------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: The output from that does not match the requested output.  For Proc3, it returns an unweighted average of 6.0.  The OP needs a weighted average of 9.0

Comment: @Anon that can easily be fixed using the change I just made.

Comment: Instead of the CASE divisor you can use: (SELECT AVG(value) FROM (VALUES ([Old]),([New])) t(value)) AS [avg]

Comment: @Anon unfortunately, that would depend on what version of sql server if they are using 2005  the values clause is not available.

Comment: @Anon Nice. Except that in SQL-Server, the average of INT values will be an INT, not a float, so casting is needed.

Comment: @Anon Updated to use a cleaner version without all the coalesce - uses a union all instead of values if they are using sql server 2005.

Comment: @bluefeet First of all there is a slight alteration to this and that is while having old and new I have a 3rd value lets call it intermediate. I tried your first solution but if there was less than 3 values I would only want to calculate the average but dividing the total by only the count of values larger than 0. Currently the solution works ok apart from this. I have put new more real data in original post to get a better idea of what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Andrew Its not clear why you want to divide each one by different denominators?  Please edit your OP with exact logic that you expect to be implemented, why does Proc1 divide by 1 and Proc2 by 3?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  [procedure],
  [Old],
  [New],
  ISNULL([Old],0) + ISNULL([New],0) [total],
  (ISNULL([Old],0) + ISNULL([New],0))/2.0 [avg]
FROM (
  SELECT
    [procedure],
    SUM([proc_time]) [proc_time],
    [proc_old_new]
  FROM MyTable
  GROUP BY [procedure],[proc_old_new]
) t
PIVOT(MIN([proc_time]) FOR [proc_old_new] IN ([Old],[New])) p
```